# Issue with build:ios -archive on Expo React Native app - How do I use Expo Cli to submit to app and play store?

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo, app-store, testflight

I am trying to push an update to the app I'm helping with that's already on the App and Play store.

It is a React Native app built with Expo.

The app itself hasn't been touched in about two years. My updates were simple - fixing a couple typos and updating to SDK 41 from 40.

Now I would like to push submit the update to the app store however I am still using Expo CL.

I type:

```
expo build:ios -t archive
```

and get:

```
There is a new version of expo-cli available (5.4.12).               
│   You are currently using expo-cli 5.4.11                               │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │


expo build:ios has been superseded by eas build. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/turtle-goes-out-to-sea-d334db2a6b60

Run the following:

› npm install -g eas-cli
› eas build -p ios https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

expo build:ios will be discontinued on January 4, 2023 (182 days left).
```

it then goes:

```
Checking if there is a build in progress...

Accessing credentials for username101 in project hoz
✔ Do you have access to the Apple account that will be used for submitting this app to the App Store? … yes

› Log in to your Apple Developer account to continue
✔ Apple ID: … rob@herdofzebras.com
› Restoring session /Users/myname/.app-store/auth/name@website.com/cookie
› Team Name Corporation (354678UXY)
› Provider Team Name (987654321)
✔ Logged in Local session
✔ Bundle identifier registered com.teamname.ios
✔ Synced capabilities
✔ Fetched Apple distribution certificates
✔ Successfully validated Distribution Certificate against Apple Servers
✔ Fetched Apple push keys
✔ Will you provide your own Apple Push Notifications service key? › Let Expo handle the process
✖ Failed to create Apple push key
Failed to set up Push Key
Failed to prepare all credentials. 
The next time you build, we will automatically use the following configuration:

Project Credential Configuration:
  Experience: @username/slug, bundle identifier: com.teamname.ios
    Provisioning profile is missing. It will be generated during the next build
    Apple Team ID: 354678UXY,  Apple Team Name: Augmented Reality Sports Management Corporation (Company/Organization)

  Distribution Certificate - Certificate ID: 1234567899
    Apple Team ID: 2529XVZUYJ,  Apple Team Name: Team Name (Company/Organization)

**You can have only two Apple Keys generated on your Apple Developer account.
Please revoke the old ones or reuse existing from your other apps.
Please remember that Apple Keys are not application specific!**
```

- **I'm new to Expo so I would also like to know, is EAS Cli supposed to
  get rid of Expo Cli?**
- **Is the goal to get to the latest SDK? The app was at 40, am I supposed to get it to 45? What does this do?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eas-cli` to submit your app even if it was built using `expo-cli`.

> I'm new to Expo so I would also like to know, is EAS Cli supposed to get rid of Expo Cli?

eas-cli will replace functionality related to building/submitting/publishing and anything else that is related to services expo provides, but it will not contain functionality related to local development e.g. `expo start/run:ios/run:android/prebuild`

> Is the goal to get to the latest SDK? The app was at 40, am I supposed to get it to 45? What does this do?

There is nothing blocking you on the expo side to upload sth build using an older SDK, but most likely it will not be accepted in AppStore because of the lack of iOS 15 support(and likely other reasons). You can check https://blog.expo.dev/ , there is a blog post that goes through the major changes in each SDK.